# jQuery lightbox: unable to call main function

Tags: jquery

http://www.samanthamakeup.tv/photo-gallery.php

On the above site, I cannot figure out why I continue to get the error of:

```
$(...).magnificPopup is not a function
```

All the needed jQuery libraries look to be loaded properly.

Answer (score 0):

At the very bottom of the source you redefine `jQuery`

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Remove that line as it creates a new instance of $ on the window that does not have `magnificPopup` plugin present.